# How convert int to string column?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Where expression:

```
 filtrationResult = filtrationResult.Where(string.Format("Convert.ToString({0}).Contains(@0)", filter.Field), filter.Value);
```

filter.Field is name column (Int32)

I get error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

How correctly convert?

Comment: something like a partial search on a number ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a switch statement with all possible values for `filter.Field`, then use the EF generated properties.

Comment: If you are using EF then I would use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`

Comment: No property or field 'SqlFunctions' exists in type 'CompanyListItem'

Comment: `SqlFunctions` is a `static` class.